Is this function on the Cantor set continuous?
Let $S = \displaystyle \prod_{n \ge 1} \{ 0, 1\}$ be the set of binary sequences, so $S$ with the product topology is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. Endow $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1} \cup \{ \infty \}$ with the subspace topology from the extended real line, so basic open subsets are either singletons of integers, or sets of the form $U_n = \{ a > n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ \infty \}$.
Define an "index function" $d:S \to \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1} \cup \{ \infty \}$ by taking $d(s)$ to be the position of the first 1, and $d(000...) = \infty$. For example, $d(00100111...) = 3$. Is $d$ continuous? The preimage of a singleton integer set $d^{-1}(n)$ is a basic open subset in the product topology, but
$$
d^{-1}(U_n) = \{000...\} \cup \bigcup_{m\ge n} d^{-1}(n)
$$
Since $S$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, $S$ has no isolated points so $\{000...\}$ is not open. Is $d^{-1}(U_n)$ open?

"is there a way to write X as a union of open sets, or is X not open?" is just a length way to mean "is X open?"

In any case, you should be able to fully describe what $d^{-1}(U_n)$ is, and then figure out whether it is open.

I have edited the question to be less redundant.

Yes, $d$ is continuous.
Another description of $d^{-1}(U_n)$ is that it is all sequences that start with $n$ zeros.
$$
d^{-1}(U_n) = \{ 00 \cdots 00a_{n+1} a_{n+2} \cdots \}
$$
This is also a basic open subset of $S$. Since the preimage of any basic open subset is open, $d$ is continuous.
